# Font awesome icons not showing up in mobile

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, font-awesome

I am using Font awesome icon in my code. They show up when i use emulator- IPhone6. But when i test in actual mobile devices, icons doesn't show.

Here is my code. I am trying to prepend the icons to an unordered list using JQuery:

```
 var icon = '<i class="fa fa-check"></i>';
 icon .prependTo($('#ulList').find("li").css("list-style-type", "none"));
```

Html:

```
<div>
      <div>
       <h4>Check these:</h4>
           <ul id="ulList">
                <li id="id1">Many conditions aply</li>
                <li id="id2">All tersm must be accepted</li>
            </ul>
       </div>
 </div>
```

Any help on this is appreciated!

Comment: You are calling `.prependTo` on a string. Maybe you meant `$(icon).prependTo`?

Comment: i tried-
$('#ulList').find("li").css("list-style-type", "none").prepend(icon);

This is not appending the icon in android phone